# UIScrollView jumpy view using UIHostingController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uikit

I would like to put a SwiftUI view into `UIScrollView` using `UIHostingController`. However my button "toggle" seems to be jumping around the view during animation, even though I'm using auto layout to constrain the view.

The following video illustrates the problem of button text jumping during aniation

[image]
import SwiftUI

```
struct ExpandableView: View {
    @State var expanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button(action: { withAnimation {expanded.toggle() }}) {
                Text("toggle")
            }
            if expanded {
                Text("long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long textlong text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long textlong text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text")
                    .font(.custom("x", fixedSize: 55))
            }
        }
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
        return sv
    }()
    
    var contentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }()
    
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: ExpandableView())
    
    private var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView.frame = view.frame
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height + 200)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = scrollView.frame
        contentView.bounds = scrollView.bounds

        controller.view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        contentView.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 100 + controller.view.intrinsicContentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way around this? I'm seeing similar behavior even in the iOS 17 beta